# Перевод аргументов в подходящий тип данных

Tags: python

**Есть строка :**

```
args = " abc 556 [d, [e, 1.14], True], 'two words' {dict:test}"
```

**Как её можно разложить по типу данных, чтобы в итоге получилось это :**

```
args = ["abc", 556, ["d", ["e", 1.14], True], "two words", {"dict":"test"}]
```

Сам пытался сделать через большое количество if/elif/else но к успеху не пришел.

Подскажите пожалуйста, как можно это адекватно реализовать.

Comment: эта строка одна или таких строк много ? откуда вобще такая?

Comment: Поддерживаются только указанные в примере типы данных?

Comment: решение подобной задачи будет неэффективным аналогично парсингу html-тегов с помощью регулярных выражений. Вероятно, данные на входе будут всегда разными и по составу и по количеству. Если вы так пытаетесь работать с аргументами команднойстроки, то обратитесь лучше к соответствующим модулям.

Comment: К примеру какие модули могут выполнить данную задачу?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно сделать так:

Объяснение на примере строки

```
args = " abc 556 [d, [e, 1.14], True], 'two words' {dict:test}"
```

Исходя из примера, предполагается, что запятые могут быть пропущены только после строк и чисел, после скобок `])}` они стоят, там где нужны.

1. Сначала строку `args` нужно "починить" - превратить содержимое в валидный код на Python. Для этого требуется обернуть строковые типы в кавычки и добавить недостающие запятые. Обычные поиск и замена здесь не подойдут, так как они затрагивают уже существующие строковые типы, например

   ```
   re.sub(',? ', ',', args)
   ```

   заменит пробел внутри `'two words'` - `'two,words'`. Следовательно, нужно отслеживать, чтобы замена не происходила внутри кавычек.
2. Я решил использовать модуль `tokenize`, которым можно разбить строку на неделимые с точки зрения интерпретатора Python атомы (токены) с указанием их типа.

   ```
   # В первом столбце тип токена
   # Во втором значение токена
   1    abc       # 1 = name. Без кавычек срока распознаётся как имя переменной.
   2    556       # 2 = number
   53   [         # 53 = operator
   1    d
   53   ,
   53   [
   1    e
   53   ,
   2    1.14
   53   ]
   53   ,
   1    True
   53   ]
   53   ,
   3    'two words' # 3 = string
   53   {
   1    dict
   53   :
   1    test
   53   }
   ```
3. Проставляем запятые. Для добавления запятой к токену, требуется выполнение следующих условий:

   - текущий токен имеет тип: число, строка, "имя переменной".
   - следующий токен не `:,}])`.
4. Оборачиваем в кавычки все токены типа "имя переменной" (кроме True, False) и меняем их тип на `string`, таким образом преобразуя их в строки. В итоге строка выглядит так:

   ```
   'abc', 556, ['d', ['e', 1.14], True], 'two words', {'dict':'test'}
   ```
5. Заключаем отремонтированную строку в квадратные скобки, чтобы на выходе получился список, и передаём методу `ast.literal_eval`. `ast.literal_eval` парсит эту строку, распознаёт типы данных и создаёт соответствующие объекты. В данном случае `ast.literal_eval` предпочтительнее `eval()`, так как имеет ограниченные возможности, что уменьшает риск исполнения вредоносного кода.

**Решение**

```
import ast
import tokenize
import io

def fixing_args(args):
    args = args.strip()
    args = io.StringIO(args).readline
    list_of_tokens = list(tokenize.generate_tokens(args))

    new_list_of_tokens = []
    need_sep_toks_types = {1, 2, 3}
    no_need_sep_toks = set(":,}])")

    for token, next_token in zip(list_of_tokens, list_of_tokens[1:]):
        separator = ',' if token.type in need_sep_toks_types and next_token.string not in no_need_sep_toks else ''

        tok_type, tok_string, *tok_others = token

        if token.type == 1 and token.string not in {"True", "False"}:
            tok_type = 3
            tok_string = f"'{token.string}'{separator}"
        else:
            tok_string = f"{token.string}{separator}"

        new_token = tokenize.TokenInfo(tok_type, tok_string, *tok_others)
        new_list_of_tokens.append(new_token)

    return tokenize.untokenize(new_list_of_tokens)

args = " abc 556 [d, [e, 1.14], True], 'two words' {dict:test}"

fixed_arg_string = fixing_args(args)
fixed_arg_string = f"[{fixed_arg_string}]"
lst_of_args = ast.literal_eval(fixed_arg_string)

for arg in lst_of_args: 
    print(arg)
```

**Output**

```
abc
556
['d', ['e', 1.14], True]
two words
{'dict': 'test'}
```

Comment: Все работает как часы, даже с очень большим количеством данных, особенно словари в словарях и.т.п. Абсолютное решение на данный момент. Очень вам благодарен!